# Finding number of files in each folder

Tags: linux, find

The following command will show the disk consumed by each folder.

```
# du */ -hs
28G     Amar/
22G     Aurang/
20G     Mu/
19G     Nag/
13G     Nash/
19G     Pun/
```

How do I know the number of files ending with .sql in each folder?

There are no sub-folder if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.sql*'
./b/a.sql
./b/c.sql
./b/b.sql
./c/a.sql
./c/d.sql
./c/c.sql
./c/b.sql
./a/a.sql
./a/b.sql

$ find . -type f -name '*.sql*' | awk -F/ '{print $2}' | uniq -c
      3 b
      4 c
      2 a
```

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly lots of ways to do this. Here is one with a simple approach:

```
 for i in *; do [[ -d $i ]] || continue; echo $i/: $(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sql' | wc -l); done
```

As you requested, this approach does not take into account the subdirectories.

Comment: @FredrikPihl thanks for enlightening me. I've modified my answer to keep its essence, but I've now taken into account your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't take it hard....just try it:

```
ls -l | grep *.sql | wc -l
```